# Can I have different chapter heading styles based on part of book?

Tags: sectioning, book-design

For example - if I use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\appendix`, and `\backmatter`... can I use `titlesec` to format the "chapters" differently? I use tikz to style my main chapters and appendix headings, but I want the table of contents and other things in the front to not use the same style, as well as my index at the back.

This is what I'm using right now for my chapter header style.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=2.50in,
  right=0.75in,
  top=1.25in,
  bottom=1.25in,
  marginparwidth=1.5in,
  marginparsep=.5in,
  asymmetric}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {
    \thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          \draw[fill=cyan!50] (0,-1) rectangle
            (25cm,3cm);
          \draw[fill=cyan!50] (0,-24) rectangle
            (25cm,-25cm);
          \ifttl@label% <---------------------- Added condition on \ifttl@label
            \node[anchor=west,xshift=.236\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
                {\color{white}\LARGE \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \Huge\thechapter};
          \fi% <------------------------------- end condition on \ifttl@label
         \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}\endgraf
    \vskip-.7cm
    \color{cyan}\Huge\raggedright\leftskip-1cm
    \MakeUppercase{#1}\endgraf
    }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does "the other" style look like?

Comment: I don't have one defined yet. Was just wondering if it can be arbitrarily changed. But I think I found something anyhow, I'm working on it to see if I can get it to work; It involves using `etoolbox` to make some conditionals and using \gappto and \gpreto to hook onto `\mainmatter` and such to toggle them

Comment: Yes, you can either define a generic style or change/switch the style altogether. [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) for patching is also good. My request for the other style was merely to have something to play with.

Answer (score 2):

OK, After a bit of poking around, I figured out that I could just hook onto the commands that I wanted to control.

I setup a toggle using etoolbox as such

```
\newtoggle{fancychapter}
```

Then I hooked onto the various section commands and toggled it as needed.

```
\gpreto{\frontmatter}{%
  \togglefalse{fancychapter}}
\gpreto{\mainmatter}{%
  \toggletrue{fancychapter}}
\gpreto{\backmatter}{%
  \togglefalse{fancychapter}}
```

After this, I added two conditionals to my custom chapter header as follows:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {
    \thispagestyle{empty}    % Remove page number on new chapters
    \iftoggle{fancychapter}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          \draw[fill=cyan!50] (0,-1) rectangle
            (25cm,3cm);
          \draw[fill=cyan!50] (0,-24) rectangle
            (25cm,-25cm);
          \ifttl@label% <---------------------- Added condition on \ifttl@label
            \node[anchor=west,xshift=.236\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
                {\color{white}\LARGE \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \Huge\thechapter};
          \fi% <------------------------------- end condition on \ifttl@label
         \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}\endgraf}%
    {\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{35pt}{0pt}{}}
    \vskip-.7cm
    \color{cyan}\Huge\raggedright\leftskip-1cm
    }
```

It's not working 100% as of yet, but the idea is there.